# How to get rid of lines within merged poligons?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2.6

Sometimes, when I merge polygons there are still some lines showing within them (see screenshot).

[image]

How can I get rid of them?

Comment: Could very well be 'dangles', annoying things! You could try using the GRASS function `v.clean` with the **rmdangle** tool and see if they get removed.

Comment: The polygon edges probably weren't coincident.  If there is a very small but complete gap between them you've created multipart polygons.  You need to fill that gap before merging to get rid of the "line".  If there are just remnant vertices because the lines over and underlapped, you can manually select those vertices and delete them. If you have a lot of these you might clean your layer first, then start merging the polygons making sure you get any slivers between them.

Comment: Hi Johns. There were no gaps before merging them, I've checked it.